# What is the best practices on creating K8s Secrets? data or StringData

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm a newbie on K8s, and now i have some questions about his best practices.

I'm creating a Secret to save my sensitive data and i came across kubernetes docs saying something about `data:`, where the content must be saved on base64 string and `stringData:` where is not needed, what is the best practice in this case, save on data or stringData?

If i choose `data:`, will be a moment when kubernetes will translate it back to it's original or i have to do it mannually?

Comment: If the Secret content is [injected into an environment variable or a file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-a-secret) it will be automatically base64-decoded.  `data:` can hold arbitrary binary data; if you have ASCII data it doesn't matter which form you use.

Answer (score 9):

In general the "stringData" is more comfortable so in the "stringData" property you can put your data in plain text and kubernetes then writes it base64 encoded for you into the "data" property of the secret. If you directly want to set the "data" property you need to manually base64 encode it